# How easy compare value of incremented const?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, compare

There are several constants TAX1, TAX2, TAX3,...,TAX_y Further array (arrSorted) of data, prices,..
I need compare value arrSorted(allRow, 8) with TAX and make some sums.
But **how increment end number of constant TAX?**

```
for i = LBound... to UBound...
  for y = 1 to 5
    if arrSorted(i,8) = TAX & y then  'i dont know how TAX & y...
       ' SUMS HERE
    end if
  next y
next i
```

I now have this recurring code (That's not very nice):

```
Function prepareData(arrSorted() As Variant)

Dim qi As Integer
Dim qy As Integer
Dim sumPrice(0 To 4, 0 To 5) As Variant

For qi = LBound(arrSorted(), 1) To UBound(arrSorted(), 1)
    Select Case arrSorted(qi, 8)
        Case Is = TAX1
            For qy = LBound(sumPrice, 2) To UBound(sumPrice, 2)
            sumPrice(0, qy) = sumPrice(0, qy) + arrSorted(qi, qy + 4)
            Next qy
        Case Is = TAX2
            For qy = LBound(sumPrice, 2) To UBound(sumPrice, 2)
            sumPrice(1, qy) = sumPrice(1, qy) + arrSorted(qi, qy + 4)
            Next qy
        Case Is = TAX3
            For qy = LBound(sumPrice, 2) To UBound(sumPrice, 2)
            sumPrice(2, qy) = sumPrice(2, qy) + arrSorted(qi, qy + 4)
            Next qy
        Case Is = TAX4
            For qy = LBound(sumPrice, 2) To UBound(sumPrice, 2)
            sumPrice(3, qy) = sumPrice(3, qy) + arrSorted(qi, qy + 4)
            Next qy
        Case Is = TAX5
            For qy = LBound(sumPrice, 2) To UBound(sumPrice, 2)
            sumPrice(4, qy) = sumPrice(4, qy) + arrSorted(qi, qy + 4)
            Next qy
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Alert!", vbCritical
    End Select
        
    Next qi
    
End Function
```

Comment: Could you share the complete code where you use those constants and where you're trying to populate `arrSorted`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant dynamically adjust variable names inside the code module during code execution.

But what you can do is put all your constants into an array and loop through the array of constants until you find the one you're looking for.

Or you could put all the constants into a [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) with their variable name as the key. So `MyDictionary("TAX1") = TAX1` is true. In your code you could do `If arrSorted(i,8) = MyDictionary("TAX" & y)`.

Here's an example of how to create a dictionary object:

```vb
    Dim MyDictionary As Object
    Set MyDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    'Putting the constants inside with their variable name as the key
    MyDictionary.Add Key:="TAX1", Item:=TAX1
    MyDictionary.Add Key:="TAX2", Item:=TAX2
    MyDictionary.Add Key:="TAX3", Item:=TAX3
    MyDictionary.Add Key:="TAX4", Item:=TAX4
    MyDictionary.Add Key:="TAX5", Item:=TAX5
    MyDictionary.Add Key:="TAX6", Item:=TAX6
    MyDictionary.Add Key:="TAX7", Item:=TAX7
    MyDictionary.Add Key:="TAX8", Item:=TAX8
    
    'How to retrieve their values
    MsgBox MyDictionary("TAX8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary and the `exists` method in place of `Select Case`.

```vb
Function prepareData(arrSorted() As Variant)

    Const TAX1 = 5
    Const TAX2 = 10
    Const TAX3 = 15
    Const TAX4 = 20
    Const TAX5 = 25

    Dim qi As Integer, qy As Integer, key As String, i As Integer
    Dim sumPrice(0 To 4, 0 To 5) As Variant

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.Add CStr(TAX1), 0
    dict.Add CStr(TAX2), 1
    dict.Add CStr(TAX3), 2
    dict.Add CStr(TAX4), 3
    dict.Add CStr(TAX5), 4

    For qi = LBound(arrSorted(), 1) To UBound(arrSorted(), 1)
        key = Trim(arrSorted(qi, 8))
        If dict.exists(key) Then
            i = dict(key)
            For qy = LBound(sumPrice, 2) To UBound(sumPrice, 2)
                sumPrice(i, qy) = sumPrice(i, qy) + arrSorted(qi, qy + 4)
            Next qy
        Else
            MsgBox "Alert! Row " & qi, vbCritical, "Value=" & key
        End If
    Next qi
    ' result
    Sheet2.Range("A1:F5").Value2 = sumPrice
End Function
```